# Determine the number of cycles of the form $(\underline{6})(\underline{2})(\underline{2})$ in $S_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

Consider a product of cycles of the form $(\underline{6})(\underline{2})(\underline{2})$ in $S_9$ where $(\underline{i})$ is a cycle with length $i$. I want to determine the number of such cycles.

However, in order for $(\underline{6})(\underline{2})(\underline{2})$ to even make sense, it must be the case that $(\underline{2})(\underline{2})$ is a product of transpositions. So if we fix $a = 1,\dots,9$, it follows that such a product can be written as
$$(ax)(ay) = (ayx)$$
where $x,y = 1,2,\dotsc,9$ and $x\neq y$. 
Therefore, the product $(\underline{6})(\underline{2})(\underline{2}) = (\underline{6})(\underline{3})$, so it follows that there are 
$$\frac{9!}{18} = 20,160$$
such elements of that form.

Is the above calculation correct? I feel as if I overcounted.

Comment: If you're allowing overlap - why not allow the 6-cycle to overlap with the 2-cycles?

Comment: What throws a spanner in the works is that it may not be the case that permutations in that form have a unique representation in that form; there may be different $6$ and $2$ cycles that produce the same permutation. (I don't have a counterexample, so there may not be as well!)

Comment: I suspect something has gone horribly wrong in the formulation of this question. As it happens, the number of elements in $S_9$ which can be written in the form $abc$ where $a$ is a $6$-cycle and $b$ and $c$ are $2$-cycles turns out to be $160740 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 19 \cdot 47$. But that's almost certainly not what the intended question is. That's approximately 88.59% of all elements in $S_9$ which are not in $A_9$ (certainly all the terms are odd so the product is not in $A_9$).

Comment: @TheoBendit It is easy to come up with examples like that. One way is to use the fact that the product $\sigma(ij)$ either splits a cycle containing both $i$ and $j$ in two, or fuses together the two cycles containing $i$ and $j$. All according to whether $i$ and $j$ were in separate cycles or not to begin with. So for example $$(123456)(35)=(1236)(45),$$ splitting the 6-cycle containing both $3$ and $5$, and then
$$(1236)(45)(34)=(123546),$$ fusing as $3$ and $4$ were in separate cycles of $(1236)(45)$.

Comment: (cont'd) Anyway, we get non-uniqueness like
$$(123456)(35)(34)=(123546)(78)(78).$$ Other kind of non-uniqueness also comes from different "fusions", such as
$$(123456)(78)(69)=(1234569)(78)=(234569)(78)(91)$$

Comment: Another way to see non-uniqueness is that there are $36$ $2$-cycles and $10080$ $6$-cycles. So the number of possible combinations is $13063680$, which is already a lot bigger than $9! = 362880$. Given that the combinations are all odd, by the pigeonhole principle there has to be at least one element which can be written in this form in at least $13063680/181440 = 72$ different ways.

Comment: Sorry guys for the confusion. It was evidently a typo. I appreciate everyone's thoughts!